# TableLayoutPanel c# pintar una celda windows forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

logre obtener la celda que estoy haciendo click en un tablelayoutpanel dinamico que creo mediante codigo, pero quisiera saber si alguno puede ayudarme a pintar esa celda en especifica, si hay un evento o una propiedad del table layout panel que te lo permita.

Mi codigo es el siguiente: Cuando hago Click en el tablelayoutpanel:

```
 private void TableLayoutPanelReservas_MouseClick(object? sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        CeldaSeleccionada = obtenerFilayColumna(e.Location,pintaCelda:true);

        if (CeldaSeleccionada.Count == 0)
            return;

        var columnProperties = tableLayoutPanelReservas.ColumnStyles.Cast<ColumnTLPReserva>().OrderBy(s => s.columName).ToList();
        var rowProperties = tableLayoutPanelReservas.RowStyles.Cast<RowTLPReserva>().ToList();
        var reservasLista = dtReservasAux.AsEnumerable().ToList();

        var itemColumna = columnProperties.Where(s => (int)s.IndexColumna == CeldaSeleccionada["Columna"]).ToList();
        var itemRow = rowProperties.Where(s => (int)s.rowIndex == CeldaSeleccionada["Fila"]).ToList();

        if (itemColumna.Count == 0 || itemRow.Count == 0)
            return;

        if (!primerReservaSelected)
        {
            primerReservaSelected = true;
            idPrimeraCarpaReserva = itemRow[0].propiedadId;
            fechaDesdeReservaSelected = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, itemColumna[0].Dia);
        }
        else
        {
            segundaReservaSelected = true;
            idSegundaCarpaReserva = itemRow[0].propiedadId;
            fechaHastaReservaSelected = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, itemColumna[0].Dia);
            //this.tableLayoutPanelReservas.GetControlFromPosition(itemColumna[0].IndexColumna, itemRow[0].rowIndex).BackColor = Color.Red;
            
            if (!this.validaReserva())
            {
                primerReservaSelected = false;
                segundaReservaSelected = false;
                fechaDesdeReservaSelected = DateTime.MinValue;
                fechaHastaReservaSelected = DateTime.MinValue;
                return;
            }

            ABM.ABMReservas frm1 = new ABM.ABMReservas(carpaId: idSegundaCarpaReserva, reservaParticionId: 0, fechaDesde: fechaDesdeReservaSelected, fechaHasta: fechaHastaReservaSelected);
            General.frmPopUp frmpopup = new General.frmPopUp();
            frmpopup.Maximizar = false;
            frmpopup.Formulario = frm1;

            if (frmpopup.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                this.ComenzarCargaPanelReservasTLP();

        }

        if(primerReservaSelected == true && segundaReservaSelected == true)
        {
            primerReservaSelected = false;
            segundaReservaSelected = false;
        }
    }
```

Ahora bien, ya obtuve la celda e hice todo lo que queria hacer, pero dentro del metodo en el cual obtengo la celda quisiera pintar en ese momento esa celda, o en el lugar que sea , pero pintar unicamente la celda seleccionada, el metodo que tengo para obtener la celda clickeada es el siguiente:

```
 private Dictionary<string,int> obtenerFilayColumna(Point puntoRecibe, bool pintaCelda = false)
    {
        Dictionary<string,int> DiccionarioRetorna = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        int row = 0;
        int verticalOffset = 0;
        //var colWidths = this.tableLayoutPanelReservas.GetColumnWidths();
        //var rowHeights = this.tableLayoutPanelReservas.GetRowHeights();
        foreach (int h in tableLayoutPanelReservas.GetRowHeights())
        {
            int column = 0;
            int horizontalOffset = 0;
            foreach (int w in tableLayoutPanelReservas.GetColumnWidths())
            {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, w, h);
                if (rectangle.Contains(puntoRecibe))
                {
                    /*if (pintaCelda)
                        tableLayoutPanelReservas.GetControlFromPosition(column, row).BackColor = Color.Red;*/                      
                    DiccionarioRetorna.Add("Fila", row);
                    DiccionarioRetorna.Add("Columna", column);                  
                    return DiccionarioRetorna;
                }
                horizontalOffset += w;
                column++;
            }
            verticalOffset += h;
            row++;
        }
        return DiccionarioRetorna;
    }
```

espero una respuesta! Gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo único que se me ocurre que funciona sería hacer un control modificado que hereda de table layout sobrescribiendo la funcion que pinta el control y metiendo dos propiedades para la celda seleccionada:

**Classe del DemoTableLayout**

```
 public class DemoTableLayout : TableLayoutPanel
    {
     
        public int SelectColumn{get;set;}
        public int SelectRow { get; set; }
        protected override void OnCellPaint(TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCellPaint(e);

  

            if(!(SelectColumn<0 && SelectRow<0))
            if (e.Column==SelectColumn &&e.Row == SelectRow)//nota esto es solo para el fondo de la celda
            {
              

                Graphics g = e.Graphics;

                g.DrawRectangle(
                    Pens.Red,
                    e.CellBounds.Location.X + 1,
                    e.CellBounds.Location.Y + 1,
                    e.CellBounds.Width - 2, e.CellBounds.Height - 2);

                g.FillRectangle(
                    Brushes.Red,
                    e.CellBounds.Location.X + 1,
                    e.CellBounds.Location.Y + 1,
                    e.CellBounds.Width - 2,
                    e.CellBounds.Height - 2);
            };
        }
    }
```

**Inicialización del tablelayout**

```
         public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        demoTableLayout1.SelectColumn = -1;//inicializacion del tablelayout por defecto 
        demoTableLayout1.SelectRow = -1;
        demoTableLayout1.Refresh();
      
    }
```

**Cambios en la funció obtenerFilayColumna**

```
       if (pintaCelda)
                    {
                        //Control control = demoTableLayout1.GetControlFromPosition(column, row).BackColor = Color.Red;//Pintar el controlador tambien
                        demoTableLayout1.SelectColumn=column;
                        demoTableLayout1.SelectRow=row;
                        demoTableLayout1.Refresh();//repinta
                        
                    }
```

Los únicos cambios son dentro del if de pintar celda que tienes comentado.
**Resultado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciono!